# Python Random Math Equation Generator program

Tags: python, tkinter

I've currently been creating a math equation generator program that will ask you random multiplication questions. I have been having trouble with the if statements where ans == answer will be equal dependent on the user's input (correct answer). However, my program does not see it as equal despite being the same value with example from printing ans and answer which shows they are the same value. I don't know if I am doing something wrong and I would like to know a method of fixing my issue.

Also when I tried to create for and while loops for the generating the equations, it would print them all out at once, is there a way to also make it so that the loop will not print a new random equation until the user gets the answer right?

```
from tkinter import *
from random import *
import random
import time
import tkinter as tk
import math
import operator
from tkinter import messagebox


#This is for creating the tkinter window and fixing the specified dimensions into place
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("900x600")

#This section creates the canvas and its specifications
canvas_width = 900
canvas_height = 500
c = Canvas(root, width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height, bg="pink")
c.pack()

def quitgame():
    root.destroy()
    
class Game_Images:
    #Background Image
    bg = PhotoImage(file="../Data/sidescroll background flip.gif")
    bg = bg.zoom(2)
    c.create_image(0,0, anchor=NW, image=bg)

    #Insert Image of Enemy
    enemy = PhotoImage(file="../Data/monke2.png")
    enemy1 = c.create_image(0,260, anchor=NW, image=enemy)

    #Insert image of playable character
    player = PhotoImage(file="../Data/monke2.png")
    player1 = c.create_image(0,325, anchor=NW, image=player)
g = Game_Images()


score = 0
x = 1

def game_start():
    global answer, question
    int_1 = random.randint(1, 12)
    int_2 = random.randint(1, 12)
    displayQuestion = "What is "+str(int_1)+ "*" + str(int_2)+"?"
    operator = ["*"]
    ops = random.choice(operator)
    c.create_rectangle(353,0,550,75, fill = "white")
    c.create_text(450, 50, font = ("Helvetica", 15), fill="pink", text = displayQuestion)
    question = str(int_1) + str(ops) + str(int_2)
    answer = int_1 * int_2

def generateQ():
    ans = e1.get()
    e1.delete(0, END)
    if ans == answer:
        score += 1
        x += 1
        print("correct")
        print(ans)
        print(answer)
    else:
        print("wrong")
        print(ans)
        print(answer)


#Buttons show up below the canvas to run commands when pressed
Button(root, text = "Commence Forth",width = 15, command = game_start).place(x=10, y=570)
Button(root, text = "Quit",width = 11, command = quitgame).place(x=800, y=570)
e1 = Entry(root)
e1.pack(padx=30, pady=30)
b=Button(root,text="Enter", width=5, font=("Helvetica", 12), command = generateQ)
b.place(x=550, y=534)

            
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: ```e1.get()``` returns a string. Comparing strings to integer is always False. ```class Game_Images``` by this, do you mean ```def Game_Images()```

Comment: @Sujay Interestingly if OP changes `class Game_Images` to `def Game_Images()`, the images will stop showing up. Look inside there is a `PhotoImage`. Right now when OP uses `g = Game_Images()` the images are stored in variables that they can access like `g.bg`. If they change it to `def ...`, they will loose the images and the images are going to be garbage collected

Comment: @TheLizzard well then two lines of adding a global list and adding an `append` method to the said list inside the function (def) could keep them from getting garbage collected, not that it is sth I suggest but that should fix Your mentioned issue

Comment: I strongly advise against using wildcard (`*`) when importing something, You should either import what You need, e.g. `from tkinter import Tk, Text, Entry` and so on or import the whole module: `import tkinter` then You can also use an alias: `import tkinter as tk` or sth like that, the point is that don't import everything unless You actually know what You are doing because today I came across an issue that was caused because of wildcard imports; name clashes are the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change function `generateQ()` like this -

```
def generateQ():
    global score,x
    ans = e1.get()
    e1.delete(0, END)
    if int(ans) == int(answer):
        score += 1
        x += 1
        print("correct")
        print(ans)
        print(answer)
    else:
        print("wrong")
        print(ans)
        print(answer)
```

Use `int()` so that they are of same data type. And use `global score,x` because it shows error. You could also write `score` and `x` as arguments.